# Convert SQL Server trigger to Oracle and master.dbo.sysprocesses - not duplicate

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql, migration, database-trigger

I tried searching but could not find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm new to SQl Server and involved into SQL Server to Oracle conversion, and it is manual conversion. All I have is SQL Server files.

I see two types of SQL Server triggers - FOR UPDATE and FOR INSERT. They look to me as before update and before insert triggers in Oracle. I'd like to confirm this please and if you can provide examples that would be great.

Also, what is the equivalent to master.dbo.sysprocesses in Oracle please? Is this v$session? I can get user from dual in Oracle. Is this what nt_username is in below code?

Here is typical code examples I need to convert to Oracle - is this before insert?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON dbo.table_name
FOR Insert AS
declare @InsertUser varchar(32)
BEGIN
SELECT @InsertUser = nt_username from master.dbo.sysprocesses where spid = @@spid
Update table_name
SET dCreateDate = GETDATE(), cCreateUser = @InsertUser
FROM table1 a ,table2 i WHERE a.tab_id = i.tab_id
END
GO
```

Update Trigger - before update?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON dbo.table_name
FOR UPDATE AS
declare @UpdateUser varchar(32)
if not update(CreateUser) and not update(CreateDate)
BEGIN
SELECT @UpdateUser = nt_username from master.dbo.sysprocesses where spid = @@spid
Update table_name
SET UpdateDate = GETDATE(), UpdateUser = @UpdateUser
FROM table1 a ,table2 i WHERE a.tab_id = i.tab_id
END
GO
```

Should I combine these two into if inserting... elsif updating in Oracle?
Thank you very much to all.

Comment: Triggers in sql server are either INSTEAD or AFTER triggers. I hope that sql server trigger is some random example because it has some serious logical issues if that is a real trigger.

Comment: Note: a `FOR [Insert/Update/Delete]` query is equivalent to an `AFTER` trigger.

Comment: @Sean Lange - Yes, this is real trigger that I need to convert. Can you please suggest how to improve this?

Comment: [`nt_username` is the "WIndows username for the process"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You should probably figure out what you want the trigger to do and write that from scratch in Oracle, rather than trying to translate these. It mostly looks like you're setting audit-type columns, which is straightforward; but not clear if you want Oracle user or O/S user, and what the other tables (in the `from` clauses) as doing.

Comment: Well for starters I would use ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins But the bigger issue is that you are updating the entire table, not the newly inserted row(s). You should be joining to inserted. Or maybe table2 is inserted and you changed the names when posting?

Comment: Thank you to Alex and Sean. Alex, I'm not sure at this moment which user I need but thank you for the info. This is all I need to figure out what is the nt_username. Sean, these are the sql server triggers that i must convert to Oracle. I did not create these, I get these from someone else. I'm trying to figure out what triggers are these - before or after. This is the first thing. And you helped with this, thank you. I'd like to have an example of good sql server trigger that is similar to this if possible please.